# checkbox checked function for two set of checkboxes in a single page, cant calll functions individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two set of input checkbox in one page. and I have added a "checked" function to each set and each has different functionality.
 I will set an example,

```
<div id="set1">
for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
<input type="checkbox" class=filter[i] onclick="clickCheck(filter[i])">array values
}
</div>


<div id="set2">
(for var j=0;j<n;j++)
<input type="checkbox" name="facets" value=array[j]>array values
}
</div>
```

Ive used jquery functions like

```
$("#set1 :checkbox").click(checkFacetSelectionCount);    
checkFacetSelectionCount()
{
$('#set1 :input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
                    alert("Checked");
}
```

and

```
clickCheck(s)
{
if ($("#set2").is(':checked')) 
  {
  alert(s);
  }
else
  {
   alert("Nothing Checked");
  }
```

, These two functions get activated on click on checkbox, so what happens is that whenever I click on any of the set, both set of functions will get activated. How can I prevent this? How can I differently call these two functions?

Comment: Could you please show your actual `clickCheck()` function? Also your example "jQuery functions" aren't valid function declarations or invocations, so it's a bit hard to see what you're trying to do - assuming those snippets were corrected where are you calling them from? (Although it's often a good idea to present a simplified version of problem code in this case it is so simplified that I for one can't work out what you're doing.)

Comment: Ive edited my question part..

Comment: What it is that you want to happen when a checkbox is clicked? If you have an `onclick="clickCheck(filter[i])"` inline in your html and also use `$("#set1 :checkbox").click(checkFacetSelectionCount)` then yes, both `clickCheck()` and `checkFacetSelectionCount()` will be called on every click of any of the "set1" checkboxes - you ask how to prevent this, but I gather the answer isn't as simple as removing one or the other from your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think that

first one should

```
$('#set1 :input[type=checkbox]:checked')
{function body;}
```

and another should

```
$('#set2 :input[type=checkbox]:checked')
       ^ 2 instead of 1
{function body;}
```

Comment: I am sorry, that was my typing mistake...I was using set2 itself...thanks for pointing that out mistake in question, Ive edited the question part, now will you be able to help me with the original issue?